# Find the Floquet multipliersfor the Markus & Yamabe system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I need some help with the following excersice.Find the **minimum period** and the **Floquet multipliers** $\bf\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}$ of the following matrix.

$A(t)=\begin{bmatrix}-1+\frac{3}{2}cos^2(t) & 1-\frac{3}{2}cos(t)sin(t)\\-1-\frac{3}{2}cos(t)sin(t) & -1+\frac{3}{2}sin^2(t)\end{bmatrix}$

It is obvious that the minimum period of A is $\pi$,just by using the double-angle formulas $\cos^2(t)=\frac{1+cos(2t)}{2},sin^2(t)=\frac{1-cos(2t)}{2}$.Furthermore by using the relation $$\prod_{i=1}^2\lambda_{i}=e^{\intop_0^T trace(A(s))ds}$$ we get easily that $\prod_{i=1}^2\lambda_{i}=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$.But now i am stuck!

Comment: Maybe take a look at http://www.math.ubc.ca/~ward/teaching/m605/every2_floquet1.pdf

Comment: See p. 121 of Hale's [Ordinary Differential Equations](https://books.google.com/books/about/Ordinary_Differential_Equations.html?id=LdTZJ4HwCv4C&redir_esc=y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two useful facts:

- $\hat x(t)=e^{t/2}\left(\begin{array}{r}-\cos t\\ \sin t\end{array}\right)$ is a solution of the Markus-Yamabe system;
- if some nontrivial solution $x(t)$ has the property $x(t+T)=\lambda x(t)$, then $\lambda$ is a Floquet 
  multiplier of the system.

Combining these two facts, we can deduce that $\lambda_1=-e^{\pi/2}$ is a multiplier of the system:
$$
\hat x(t+\pi)=e^{(t+\pi)/2}\left(\begin{array}{r}-\cos (t+ \pi)\\ \sin (t+\pi)\end{array}\right)
=e^{\pi/2}e^{t/2}\left(\begin{array}{r}\cos t\\ -\sin t\end{array}\right)=
-e^{\pi/2}\hat x(t).
$$
Another multiplier can be obtained from the equality $\lambda_1 \lambda_2= e^{-\pi/2}$.

Comment: thank you for the correction.As for the solution $\widehat{x(t)}$ you suggest is it out of the blue or it can be derived somehow?

Comment: @Perpendicular This solution is a part of the Markus-Yamabe counterexample: it is unbounded and, thus, the origin is not globally asymptotically stable, although the eigenvalues of $A(t)$ do have negative real parts for any $t$. I.e. the system was specially designed to have this solution. There is no general way to find such a solution in any case.

Comment: For a paper on how to construct such examples, see Josić and Rosenbaum [Unstable Solutions of Nonautonomous Linear Differential Equations](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/060677057) (however, I am afraid that the paper is behind a paywall).